# Concatenación de valores en python

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito "concatenar" los valores que hay duplicados en función de el valor de una columna. Por ejemplo los valores 'madrid 123 NaN' y 'NaN 123 cristiano' como comparten numero que quedaran como única fila que pusiera 'madrid 123 cristiano'.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```python
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

rciudades=pd.read_csv('ciudades.csv')
rpersonajes=pd.read_csv('personajes.csv')
rtodo=glob.glob("./*.csv")
rtodito=pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in rtodo))

print(rtodito)
```

Comment: Usa texto en lugar de imagenes. Asi se puede copiar y pegar código y datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas en Postgresql se llama left join. Al parecer, el equivalente a esto en pandas es [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) pasando left en el argumento how.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["madrid", 123],
                    ["barca", 456],
                    ["psg", 789],
                    ["dante", 111]],
                   columns=("ciudad", "telefono"))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["cristiano", 123, "a"],
                    ["mesi", 456, "a"],
                    ["mbappe", 789, "a"],
                    ["color", 222, "a"]],
                   columns=("personaje", "telefono", "letra"))

print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on="telefono", how="left"))
```

Referencias:

- https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/joins-in-pandas-master-the-different-types-of-joins-in-python